# Invalid column name '#Results'

Tags: sql-server

```
alter PROCEDURE sp_Get_CustInfoSerach2    
      (@PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
      ,@ColumnName VARCHAR(50)=null
      ,@Value VARCHAR(50)=null
      ,@ddlValue VARCHAR(50)=null
      ,@txtValue VARCHAR(50)=null
      ,@status varchar(30))
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
      if @txtValue IS NULL  
      Begin
        SET @Value = ''''+@ddlValue+ ''''
        End                
        else if @ddlValue IS NULL  
        begin
        SET @Value = ''''+@txtValue+ ''''
        end
      SET @cmd = 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY C_Register.UserId desc 
      )AS RowNumber

      ,C_Register.UserId, C_Register.Name, C_Register.UserName, C_Register.Status, 
                    Packages.PackagePeriod, Packages.PackageName, C_Register.ActivationDate, 
                      Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate, Receive_Payment.Balance, Receive_Payment.PyingAmount, 
                      Receive_Payment.LastPaidDate, C_Register.LastUpdateTime, 
                      Area.AreaName, C_Register.MobNo, Employee.EmpName, C_Register.Address,C_Register.CreatedDate

     INTO'+ #Results+'
      FROM C_Register INNER JOIN Receive_Payment ON C_Register.UserId = Receive_Payment.UserId
                       INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId
                       INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
                       INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
     where      C_Register.AccountExpiry= Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And C_Register.Status = '+@status+'And
     ' +  @ColumnName + ' = ' + @Value 

      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
      EXEC(@cmd)
END
```

throwing error:

> Invalid column name '#Results'.

how to solve it?

Comment: i think you did not declare Results variable into your storedprocedure

Comment: How about don't build up SQL - how about use parameters instead? Fewer mistakes that way

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with C#, paging, or gridview

Comment: Before this query I created same without quotes so its executing but here i add just quotes for pass parameter as coloumn

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly you should first exec dynamic sql before select from temporary table

```
Alter PROCEDURE sp_Get_CustInfoSerach2
(
@PageIndex INT = 1 ,
@PageSize INT = 10 ,
@RecordCount INT OUTPUT ,
@ColumnName VARCHAR(50)=null ,
@Value VARCHAR(50)=null ,
@ddlValue VARCHAR(50)=null ,
@txtValue VARCHAR(50)=null ,
@status varchar(30)
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)

If @txtValue IS NULL
Begin 
SET @Value = ''''+@ddlValue+ '''' 
End
Else 
if @ddlValue IS NULL
Begin 
SET @Value = ''''+@txtValue+ '''' 
End 
SET @cmd = 'SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY C_Register.UserId desc )AS RowNumber,
  C_Register.UserId, C_Register.Name, C_Register.UserName, C_Register.Status, 
                Packages.PackagePeriod, Packages.PackageName, C_Register.ActivationDate, 
                  Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate, Receive_Payment.Balance, Receive_Payment.PyingAmount, 
                  Receive_Payment.LastPaidDate, C_Register.LastUpdateTime, 
                  Area.AreaName, C_Register.MobNo, Employee.EmpName, C_Register.Address,C_Register.CreatedDate

 INTO #Results
  FROM C_Register INNER JOIN Receive_Payment ON C_Register.UserId = Receive_Payment.UserId
                   INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId
                   INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
                   INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
 where      C_Register.AccountExpiry= Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And C_Register.Status = '+@status+'And
 ' +  @ColumnName + ' = ' + @Value 

  /*First Execute above dynamic Sql query */
  EXEC(@cmd)
 /* From the above execute statemnet the query will executed and temporary table will created on the fly */

  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results


  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your query is creation of temp table thats not right way to create temp table inside `dynamic query`.

But even if you create `temp table` inside a `dynamic query` it can be `accessed` only **inside** the `session` of `dynamic query`. If you try to select the temp outside of dynamic query which is created inside the dynamic query you will get a error saying object doesnot exist.

Since you know the number of columns present in the result of dynamic query you can create the `temp table` outside of dynamic query and `insert` the records through dynamic query.

Try changing your procedure like this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_get_custinfoserach2 (@PageIndex   INT = 1, 
                                        @PageSize    INT = 10, 
                                        @RecordCount INT output, 
                                        @ColumnName  VARCHAR(50)=NULL, 
                                        @Value       VARCHAR(50)=NULL, 
                                        @ddlValue    VARCHAR(50)=NULL, 
                                        @txtValue    VARCHAR(50)=NULL, 
                                        @status      VARCHAR(30)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET nocount ON; 

      DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max) 

      IF @txtValue IS NULL 
        BEGIN 
            SET @Value = '''' + @ddlValue + '''' 
        END 
      ELSE IF @ddlValue IS NULL 
        BEGIN 
            SET @Value = '''' + @txtValue + '''' 
        END 
/*create a temp as same structure of your dynamic query select statement*/
      CREATE TABLE #result 
        ( 
           rownum         INT, 
           userid         INT, 
           NAME           VARCHAR(100), 
           username       VARCHAR(100), 
           status         VARCHAR(15), 
           packageperiod  VARCHAR(15), 
           packagename    VARCHAR(100), 
           activationdate DATETIME, 
           oldexpirydate  DATETIME, 
           balance        NUMERIC(22, 4), 
           pyingamount    NUMERIC(22, 4), 
           lastpaiddate   DATETIME, 
           lastupdatetime DATETIME, 
           areaname       VARCHAR(100), 
           mobno          INT, 
           empname        VARCHAR(100), 
           address        VARCHAR(5000), 
           createddate    DATETIME 
        ) 

      SET @cmd = 
       ' Insert into #result 
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C_Register.UserId desc )AS RowNumber,
         C_Register.UserId, C_Register.Name, C_Register.UserName,   
        C_Register.Status, Packages.PackagePeriod, Packages.PackageName, 
        C_Register.ActivationDate,Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate, 
        Receive_Payment.Balance, Receive_Payment.PyingAmount, 
        Receive_Payment.LastPaidDate, C_Register.LastUpdateTime, 
        Area.AreaName, C_Register.MobNo, Employee.EmpName,
        C_Register.Address,C_Register.CreatedDate       
        FROM C_Register 
        INNER JOIN Receive_Payment 
                ON C_Register.UserId = Receive_Payment.UserId
        INNER JOIN Area 
                ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId
        INNER JOIN Employee 
                ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
        INNER JOIN Packages 
                ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
         where      C_Register.AccountExpiry= Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And C_Register.Status = ' + @status + ' And ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + @Value 

    SELECT @RecordCount = Count(*) 
    FROM   #results 

    SELECT * 
    FROM   #results 
    WHERE  rownumber BETWEEN( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1 AND( ( 
                            ( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1 ) + 
                                 @PageSize ) - 1 

    DROP TABLE #results 

    EXEC(@cmd) 
END
```

**Note :** I have given generic `datatypes` to `temp` table columns please change the `datetypes` according to your `schema`.

Comment: I was trying to execute same ur mentioned qury but again throwing #result unknown error.So I changed like below